# How to convert columns in and R tibble that are lists, which contain NULL values so the output is a tibble with no lists and NA replacing the NULLs

Tags: r, dplyr

The R tibble that is output from a dplyr pivot_wider operation creates some columns that are characters and other columns that are lists. I understand this occurs because there are some duplicate names_from combinations in the pivot_wider process. The list columns also contain NULL values and when listing the header the result looks like this:

```r
> head(test)
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  SAMPLE_NO SAMPLE_ANALYSIS_NO `SiO2_%_AES` `LOI_%_AES`
  <chr>     <chr>              <list>       <list>     
1 16821     11456              <chr [1]>    <chr [1]>  
2 16825     11461              <chr [1]>    <NULL>     
3 16829     11466              <chr [1]>    <chr [1]>  
4 16833     11471              <chr [1]>    <chr [1]>  
5 16836     11477              <chr [1]>    <chr [1]>  
6 16837     11479              <chr [1]>    <chr [1]>
```

... while when viewed in RStudio the tibble looks like this:

[image: Tibble with lists in RStudio]

This indicates to me that the lists are using some clever process to save memory space as in the full tibble the are several 100,000s of rows and several 1000s of columns that are lists like the example here. The clever part is that the list just stores all the unique values found in a particular column, for example in the first list column there are only 43 possible outcomes, and then uses this structure (that I don't fully understand) to place the correct value in a row where required and NULL otherwise

Now I would like to transform this tibble so I have a tibble (or data frame) without list columns (just character columns only) and also output NA rather than NULL in the output. I've been fluffing around for a few hours on this interesting puzzle but now it's time to get some help as I'm stumped.  The example data is this linked [RDS object](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuFS5ygWevymg6Zwfc82bTxlKhd4zA?e=HLVdqi) should you wish to help.

UPDATE: Following the suggestion from Jon Spring below here is the output from `dput(head(test))`

```
structure(list(SAMPLE_NO = c("16821", "16825", "16829", "16833", 
"16836", "16837"), SAMPLE_ANALYSIS_NO = c("11456", "11461", "11466", 
"11471", "11477", "11479"), `SiO2_%_AES` = list("73.4", "72.7", 
    "73", "73.6", "69.8", "74"), `LOI_%_AES` = list("1.86", NULL, 
    "1.6", "1.8", "1.6", "1.6")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: It will be most helpful if you can share a sample of the data frame as code in the question itself. That protects users from needing to download a random file from a stranger, and ensures the question will be reproducible in the future even if your link eventually rots. If you run `dput(head(test))`, you can paste the output into the body of your question.

Comment: *"lists are using some clever process to save memory space"* -- I don't think so. The list-columns are a way in R to go outside of the "normal" expectation of a `data.frame` column. That is, we normally expect that a column (a) it may have `NA` but has no `NULL`; (b) all elements are the same class, which is actually a constraint of a vector/array in general; and (c) always exactly 1 value per row of the frame, no more no less. If any of that is violated (due to intent or an under-conditioned reshape), then either we `stop(.)` with an error or we use list-columns.

Comment: If you expect that you should have exactly one value per row and you don't, then I suggest you go back to why the reshaping is creating list-columns and fix it there instead of doing post-pivot remediation. (The fact that your `%` columns are `chr [1]`, if they were not before the pivot, suggests that different-class columns were somehow combined.)

Comment: You cannot just `tidyr::unnest` what you have here, though, since at least in row two you have a different number of embedded elements, so ... back to why the pivot created them in the first place.

Comment: All useful advice ... agree it would be better not to have this problem in the first place.  The pivot does report several 1000 duplicates for the concatenation of 3 fields (chemical, its units, and assay method), so this must be the cases where something has been assayed more than once in the same units by the same method.  I'll have a play with removing these before pivoting and see if that results in a better outcome.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that it may be worth it in the long run to fix the pivot/reshape/aggregation that created the list-columns, but in the near-term:

```r
test <- tibble(SAMPLE_NO = 1:6, SAMPLE_ANALYSIS_NO = 11:16, SiO2 = as.list(letters[1:6]), LOI = replace(as.list(LETTERS[1:6]), 2, list(NULL)))
test
# # A tibble: 6 × 4
#   SAMPLE_NO SAMPLE_ANALYSIS_NO SiO2      LOI      
#       <int>              <int> <list>    <list>   
# 1         1                 11 <chr [1]> <chr [1]>
# 2         2                 12 <chr [1]> <NULL>   
# 3         3                 13 <chr [1]> <chr [1]>
# 4         4                 14 <chr [1]> <chr [1]>
# 5         5                 15 <chr [1]> <chr [1]>
# 6         6                 16 <chr [1]> <chr [1]>

library(dplyr)
test %>%
  mutate(across(c(SiO2, LOI), ~ sapply(.x, function(z) if (length(z)) z[[1]] else NA)))
# # A tibble: 6 × 4
#   SAMPLE_NO SAMPLE_ANALYSIS_NO SiO2  LOI  
#       <int>              <int> <chr> <chr>
# 1         1                 11 a     A    
# 2         2                 12 b     NA   
# 3         3                 13 c     C    
# 4         4                 14 d     D    
# 5         5                 15 e     E    
# 6         6                 16 f     F
```

This relies wholly on the list elements having length 0 or 1, nothing more. If there are any more, the `z[[1]]` will silently discard the remainder of the cell's elements. While this does not assume that all elements are the same class going in, it will be a side-effect if some of the elements are not-string and at least one is a string, as everything will be coerced to `character`.

Comment: r2evans ... that worked very well ... I just ran your suggestion over the dataframe with 165,000 rows and 3,284 columns and it did the job in about 5 minutes!

Answer (score 0):

I did work out a clunky part solution on a by-column basis that I could then set in a loop to run through all the list columns in the tibble as follows:

```
# Subset a column that is a list
x <- test$`SiO2_%_AES`

# Make an empty dataframe for this column
y <- data.frame(`SiO2_%_AES`= character())

# Function to test for NULL and make NA if exists
handle_null <- function(x){
  if(is.null(x)){
      return(NA)
  } else {
    return(x)
  }
}

# Loop through the column
for (i in 1:length(x)){
  z <- handle_null(x[[i]])
  y <- rbind(y, z)
}

names(y) <- "SiO2_%_AES"

# Result looks OK
print(y)

   SiO2_%_AES
1        73.4
2        72.7
3          73
4        73.6
5        69.8
6          74
7          72
8        72.2
9        72.7
10         71
11       71.9
12       <NA>
13       <NA>
14       72.8
15       72.2
```

However, as you would expect with an IF function running in a loop within R it's very slow when you have 165000 lines and 3500 columns to process.

Comment: Your `handle_null` is _exactly_ what my `sapply(...)` is doing. I thought you needed it in [tag:dplyr]?

Comment: BTW, iteratively adding rows to a frame using `rbind(y, x)` works in practice but scales *horribly*, see "Growing Objects" in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). For each row added, it makes a complete copy of all rows in `old`, which works but starts to slow down a lot. It is far better to produce a list of these new rows and then `rbind` them at one time; e.g., `out <- list(); for (...) { out <- c(out, list(newrow)); }; alldat <- do.call(rbind, out);`. (Or do it inline as in my answer, much more efficient.)

Comment: Thanks for the comments r2evans ... I've never really understood sapply and its other apply friends so I usually avoid it and look more transparent solutions ... however, in this case, it looks to be quite handy.